# How to play audio from different applications on different output devices?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, soundcard

How can I play music on my speakers while I use my headset for video chat applications like Skype?

Shouldn't this be possible via this PulseAudio sound server that Ubuntu uses?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Routing sound to different sinks with PulseAudio

Yes this is possible, but **you need more than one soundcard** (PulseAudio calls these sinks) for this to work. Don't worry, if you have something like a headset that is connected via Bluetooth or USB, then this also counts as another soundcard.

### Using the PulseAudio GUI

While you can configure PulseAudio from the terminal with `pacmd` ([manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man5/pulse-cli-syntax.5.html)), you don't need to! There is a GUI application called [PulseAudio Volume Control](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol/) that offers this functionality.

[image: screenshot of pavucontrol showing active applications and a button for each that brings up a dropdown menu with the available soundcards, two in this case]

### Using plugins for applications

- If you are already using **VLC**, you should check that `vlc-plugin-pulse` is [installed](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/vlc-plugin-pulse/). You can then switch between soundcards from within VLC via menu entries *Audio > Audio devices*.

Comment: Thanks. I have one sound card, one bluetooth headset and BT Speakers. I could route Skype to headset, Chrome to system volume, and Rythmbox to speakers. It is pretty cool.

Comment: So will it not work with, for instance, headphones connected via a 3.5mm jack?

Comment: Do you by chance know of a way to set this for system notifications? They only play for a really short time, so I can't catch them in this UI to set the sink.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann I tried to keep the answer simple when I wrote it a long time ago. My best guess is that you may find a PulseAudio configuration file where you can change this setting. Sorry that I can't provide a better answer to your problem, I'd look into if I had time available, but my schedule is very cramped.

Comment: @LiveWireBT No worries, thanks. I've asked a new question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1370468/can-i-get-the-notification-sound-play-on-a-different-audio-device