# Lubuntu USB sound card managing

Tags: sound, usb, lubuntu, alsa

I've been trying to use an old Asus EeePC901 to record and play music along with an USB M-Audio M-track-plus. I use Audacity 2.0.5. Already tried lots of Linux distros, and Lubuntu looks to be the one for Audacity & M-Audio to work perfectly.

BUT...

It would be nice to keep USB M-audio to play music from the Internet, and from my own audio files. That doesn't happen.

Audacity immediately recognized USB M-Audio with no issues, EVEN THOUGH Alsa mixer keeps on Intel internal audio card.

Alsa mixer do recognize USB M-Audio card but do not use it saying that there are no parameteres available.

The question is: why is USB M-Audio card available for Audacity with no issues, and Alsa will not use it for other applications, like music players or Web browsers...?

Thanks is advance for your support. All the best, RC

Answer (score 3):

PulseAudio is used on top of ALSA to manage applications use of your onboard soundcard. However, it is not preloaded in a standard Lubuntu install. To get PulseAudio open your terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol
```

Comment: Installing PulseAudio solved the problem. Thanks very much...!

Comment: No Problem. Don't forget to mark the problem as solved.

Comment: @Duck thank you so much for this! I'm using Kubuntu 15.10 and could not get my external usb card to be default till I installed pavucontrol and turned off the other sound options. Wow, it shouldn't be this difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Audacity uses ALSA.

The default card is whatever card has been seen first.

To change the order of the sound drivers, add the following lines at the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf`:

```
options snd-usb-audio index=0
options snd-hda-intel index=1
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

> Audacity immediately recognized USB M-Audio with no issues, EVEN THOUGH Alsa mixer keeps on Intel internal audio card.

To my knowledge `alsamixer` doesn't manage which application uses which interface/soundcard/output, you can only set the software controls (some may have only hardware controls and don't offer any software controls) for the devices detected by Alsa.

The default Ubuntu desktop installation uses PulseAudio on top of Alsa to manage which application uses which soundcard. The same should apply for Lubuntu.

In Unity this functionality can be accessed and managed through the volume indicator or the system settings menu.

Related: [How to play audio from different applications on different output devices?](https://askubuntu.com/q/448618/40581)